# Load php.ini to terminal

Tags: php, wampserver, composer-php, git-bash, php-ini

I'm using Git Bash terminal, php 5.4.10, OpenServer (wamp), windows 7

I am trying to load some library by Composer, but I can not because it says:

[image]

Kinda weird because curl is working at php

[image]

but, for some reasons, php.ini file was not loaded to git bash terminal.

[image]

Why? How I can init php.ini at terminal and made it work?

Comment: What is the value of `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` if you load the phpinfo site with your browser?

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path -> C:\Windows  
  
Loaded Configuration File -> E:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\config\php.ini

Comment: Can you access the file form terminal?

Comment: do you mean $ php -r "echo php_ini_loaded_file();" ? this returned false, so no, I can not

Comment: no. I mean `cat  E:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\config\php.ini`

Comment: yes, this has access to file

Comment: what gives you `$ which php` ?

Comment: wow: /e/OpenServer/modules/php/PHP-5.3.20/php

Comment: but anyway, just moment ago I switched php version to 5.3.20 at Wamp, and run "php -em" again, still have no curl in the list (but curl extension is uncommented at php.ini for 5.3.20 too)

Comment: sure.. by that way, there were not php.ini file, only php.ini-development and php.ini-production files. I have simply added php.ini to this path and terminal loaded him. This looks like ugly hack, because now i have two php.ini files, maybe i can change php.ini loading path from e:\openserver\modules\php\php-5.3.20\ to e:\openserver\userdata\temp\config ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27285/discussion-between-denis-and-hek2mgl)

Comment: Sorry Denis, I was not available for short, yes we continue in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your phpinfo() web output look for the loaded php.ini file, then start PHP with it

`php -c c:\windows\apache2\php.ini`

for example.

You might also consider simply copying the web ini file to the location it's being looked for at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
$ php --ini
```

To see which `php.ini` is used in CLI (this can be different from the ini file used on the web). You should go to that ini file and enable the extension there.

Comment: look at 3-rd attached image)